# How to set more than 1 default value for the SET type in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, set

I have a column called 'responsable', this is a `set` type data which can have these values:

```
`responsable` SET('creator', 'owner', 'amdmin', 'dev', 'client', 'operator')
```

By default this field to select 'client' and 'operator', so I tried something like this:

```
CHANGE COLUMN `responsable` `responsable`
SET('creator', 'owner', 'amdmin', 'dev', 'client', 'operator')
NULL DEFAULT 'client','operator';
```

Which doesn't work (error near 'operator')

How to set more than 1 default value in set type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set.html) is represented by a single string value.

> A `SET` is a string object that can have zero or more values, each of
>   which must be chosen from a list of permitted values specified when
>   the table is created. `SET` column values that consist of multiple set
>   members are specified with members separated by commas (,). A
>   consequence of this is that `SET` member values should not themselves
>   contain commas.

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table CHANGE COLUMN `responsable` `responsable`
  SET('creator', 'owner', 'amdmin', 'dev', 'client', 'operator')
    NULL DEFAULT 'client,operator';
```

[db-fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o4NoZzF2aWfJYVv2z6c96u/0)

However - I would advise to not use SET data type at all. Since it is nothing else but a comma delimited list, most disadvantages described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) aplay to it. Consider to normalize the schema and use a separate table `responsibilities`.

For example: If a user with `user_id = 253` has the responsibilities `client`  and `operator`, you would have two entries in the `responsibilities` table:

```
user_id | responsibility
--------|---------------
    253 | client
    253 | operator
```

Comment: It works, I couldn't find any reference or help about this anywhere (I even looked for it in the MySQL documentation), than you!

Comment: @stramin The first example in the docs is `SET('one', 'two')` and one of the values is `'one,two'`.